# Improve a Select Case

Tags: excel, vba

I took a spreadsheet to provide maintenance here at the company and I don't know much about VBA.

Whenever the user needs to use the spreadsheet, the user needs to edit the VBA code, this is bad, if He already fills in the CAST_PROJECT in the spreadsheet, why have to fill it in the case again?

If there is a possibility for the user to tune the CST_PLAN in the spreadsheet, why type in the VBA code?

Anyway, I would like a help to improve this code so that the user does not have to type anything else in VBA, but directly in the spreadsheet, both **CST_PLAN** and **CAST_PROJECT**, what is the best way for that?

```
Public Sub DefinirProjeto()
    CST_PROJECT = Planilha6.Cells(2, 3) 
       
    Select Case CST_PROJECT
        Case "Test"
            CST_PLAN = 87184
        Case "Test2"
            CST_PLAN = 41866
        Case "Test3"
            CST_PLAN = 45863
        End Select
    End Sub
```

[image: vba]

Comment: You didn't explain this quite well. Are you saying that when there is a new `Case`, the user has to add a new `CST_PLAN` value in the `Select Case` code? If so, you have to put the values somewhere, usually in another worksheet where the values will be manually updated (added). Anyway, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Currently the VBA reads the CST_PROJECT from the spreadsheet, I want it to also read the CST_PLAN instead of always having to open the code and include one more line in the case.

Sorry if I didn't know how to express myself correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As you are doing a 121 mapping you could maintain the mapping in Planilha6, then read that into a dictionary, via an array, then use the dictionary to manage your lookups (rather than select case). You can always retrieve from dictionary, with a Select Case inside a loop over its keys, if Select Case is later needed.

```
Public Sub DefinirProjeto()
    Dim data() As Variant, lookups As Object, i As Long
    
    data = Sheet6.Range("B3:C" & GetLastRow(Sheet6, 2)).Value  'Planilha6
    Set lookups = GetDictFromArray(data)
    
    For Each Key In lookups.keys
    
        Debug.Print "CST_PROJECT=" & Key, vbTab, " CST_PLAN=" & lookups(Key)
    
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetDictFromArray(ByRef data() As Variant) As Object
    Dim i As Long, dict As Object
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
       dict(data(i, 1)) = data(i, 2)
    Next
    Set GetDictFromArray = dict
End Function
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new variable and changing the way of making the case. As below.

> Public CST_PLANTEST As String

```
Public Sub DefinirProjeto()
    CST_PROJECT = Planilha6.Cells(2, 3) 
    CST_PLANTEST = Planilha6.Cells(3, 3)
    
    Select Case CST_PROJECT

        Case "PAT"
            CST_PLAN = CST_PLANTEST

    End Select
    
End Sub
```